# Horizontal RecycleView Item click scroll to first item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello guys i am having an issue with Horizontal Recycle View in which if am scroll to right then click on any item then it automatically scroll to first item in left , basically i have to stay on current clicked position not to scroll to start left , i use multiple thing from stack but none of them worked like scrolltopostion, creating custom layout manager class !!! Please Help
Below is my code:

```
  private void setAdapter() {
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mainAdapterClass = new MainAdapterClassw(context, AuctionManager.list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapterClass);
}
```

Below is adapter Class:

```
    public class MainAdapterClassw extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapterClassw.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<AuctionBean> list;
    Context context;
    public MainAdapterClassw(Context context, ArrayList<AuctionBean> list) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.customelayout, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        auctionBean = list.get(i);
        viewHolder.top_sr_no.setText(auctionBean.getAuction_id());
        viewHolder.view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(selectedPos == i);

        viewHolder.bottom_sr_no.setText(auctionBean.getReserve_price());

            text_qantity.setText(qantity1);
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load("http://traala.com/Bidding/images/date.png")
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .into(productimage);

        }
        viewHolder.setClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                AuctionBean auctionBean1 = list.get(position);
                Log.d("LogPosition",position+"");

                if (countDownTimer != null) {

                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                }

                    CSPreferences.putString(context, "auction_id", auctionBean1.getAuction_id());
                    ModelManager.getInstance().getAuctionManager().AuctionManager(context, Operations.getallAcuntion(context,
                            ActionString.getall_auctions, "101", auctionBean1.getAuction_id()));


            }
        });

        switch (auctionBean.getAuction_status()) {
            case "status_active.png":
                viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.status_active);
                break;
            case "status_pending.png":
                viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(status_pending);
                break;
            case "status_over.png":
                viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_icon_auction_red);
                break;


        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView top_sr_no;
        public TextView bottom_sr_no;
        View view2;
        private ItemClickListener clickListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            top_sr_no = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textsrno);
            bottom_sr_no = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textbottom_srno);
            view2 = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        }

        public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            this.clickListener = itemClickListener;

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)   {
            clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), false);
            adapterpostion =getAdapterPosition();
            auctionstatus =auctionList.get(getAdapterPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            clickListener.onClick(view, getPosition(), true);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` this property in your xml layout file where you put `Recyclerview`.

Comment: in parent layout of xml ?

Comment: yes, like if your recyclerview inside `LineareLayout` then add that property in LinearLayout

Comment: not solved :( !!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a problem with multiple listeners. Try leaving only one assignment of `.setOnClickListener`. And what does `ItemClickListener` class do?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this property in your parent layout in xml file

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Set adapter in RecyclerView as below:

```
private void setAdapter() {
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mainAdapterClass = new MainAdapterClassw(context, AuctionManager.list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapterClass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was occurred because of `gravity` property inside `EditText`, It was like: `android:gravity="center"`, So removing this property resolved the issue.